# How to check if Certain programs are installed and if they are display message

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that will check if Program A,B,C and D is installed. If so display message to say they are all installed else say they are not installed.

From research i have created the following script.

```
    $ProgramList = @("A","B","C","D")
    
    
     ForEach ($Program in $ProgramList){
     
        Function Get-InstalledApps
        {
        $Regpath = @(
                'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
                'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            )
        Get-ItemProperty $Regpath | .{Process{If($_.DisplayName) { $_ } }}
        
        }
        
        
      
        $Result = Get-InstalledApps | Where {$_.DisplayName -like "*$Program*"}
    
         
       
        If ($Result) {
            [Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("INSTALLED")
        } Else { 
            [Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("NOT INSTALLED")
        }
        }
```

My issue is when i run this i get 4 message boxes popup to say the program is installed. i'm trying to make this so it will just give a single message box. if all are installed and if one or more is not installed another message box to say the programs are not installed.

Any help is greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Just something to note, not all applications register themselves under these keys.  This should work fine if you're working with known applications in your environment where you can test this out, but don't expect it to work with any random set of applications.

Comment: Thank  you for the information. I will only be using this for a defined set of applications that are found under these keys. I have tested and all the applications that i need are found here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting four pop-ups because your calling the msgbox four times (as it's within your loop).  Just moving it out doesn't completely solve your problem since it's going to only look at the last one, but if you need to do it the way you are, then something like this would work:

```
$ProgramList = @("A","B","C","D")

$allInstalled = $true # Assume they're all installed
    
ForEach ($Program in $ProgramList){
     
    Function Get-InstalledApps {
        $Regpath = @(
                'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
                'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            )
        Get-ItemProperty $Regpath | .{Process{If($_.DisplayName) { $_ } }}
        
    }
      
    If(-not(Get-InstalledApps | Where {$_.DisplayName -like "*$Program*"})) {
        # We know at least one isn't installed
        $allInstalled = $false
    }

}

If($allInstalled) {
    [Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("INSTALLED")
} Else { 
    [Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("NOT INSTALLED")
}
```

If you're able to tweak the function a bit, you can speed it up by only pulling in the registry information once.  The BEGIN section here runs just once when you call the function with multiple applications.

```
Function Test-InstalledApps {

    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$appName
    )

    Begin {
        $Regpath = @('HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*','HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*')
        $allApps = Get-ItemProperty $Regpath | Select DisplayName 
        $allAppsInstalled = $true
    }

    Process {
        ForEach($app in $appName) {
            If(-Not($allApps | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*$app*" })) {
                # We know at least one isn't installed
                $allAppsInstalled = $false
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        Return $allAppsInstalled
    }
    
}

If(Test-InstalledApps @("A","B","C")) {
    [Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("INSTALLED")
} Else { 
    [Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("NOT INSTALLED")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, This works perfectly. using your tweaked version of the function makes this run much quicker. I have implemented this and it's now doing exactly as i need. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bit better approach, using `Out-GridView`. In my opinion this would look cleaner, I know this is not answering your question but it might suit you better:

```
$programList = @(
    'SomeRandomProgram1'
    'Microsoft Visual'
    '7-Zip'
    'SomeRandomProgram2'
)

$Regpath = @(
    'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
)

$installedPrograms = (Get-ItemProperty $Regpath).where({$_.DisplayName})
$result = foreach($program in $programList)
{
    $check = $installedPrograms.DisplayName -match $program
    if($check)
    {
        foreach($match in $check)
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Program = $program
                Status = 'Found'
                Match = $match
            }
        }
        continue
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Program = $program
        Status = 'Not Found'
        Match = $null
    }
}

$result | Out-GridView
```

In my computer the OGV looks like this:

[image: exampleogv]

Comment: In this use case i'm just wanting a message box to popup to say if they are installed or not. Thank you for highlighting Out-GridView. This will help with another function I'm writing.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the game here and my answer is you might say completely different buy I did it on a quest to learn a few things and thought others might find it interesting. It produces output like this.

[image]

The interesting part is that the menu is self adjusting, within screen size limits, so you can search for more or fewer programs just by passing them in an array. The program searched directories vs the Registry so you can locate programs which are not installed (portable). By default it searches the two Windows locations but you can also pass it an array with additional search locations.

I'm sure it wouldn't take to much to modify to have it search the registry keys instead.

If you're interested you can download a zip file (needed to include the graphics files for the check mark and red x from my [OneDrive here.](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=50B4DFA90B96FF40&resid=50B4DFA90B96FF40%217603&authkey=AKzlqvMyQdAzoZ8)